# Why is magento sometime shows a blank page and sometime redirects to same admin login page after admin login?

Tags: php, magento, redirect

I am using magento 1.8.1.0. While transferring magento from local server to live server, I could not log-in to admin dashboard. Sometime it shows blank page and sometime it redirects to same admin log-in page.

I googled a lot about this issue and tried all possible solution i found like following:

1. commenting out some elements of $configParams array in Varien.php
2. In database table core_config_data, i changed "web/unsecure/base_url" and "web/secure/base_url/" to "http://example.com/", changed "web/cookie/cookie_path" to "/" and "web/cookie/cookie_domain" to ".example.com"
3. Edited "app/etc/local.xml" file and kept correct mysql hostname, username, password, and database name
4. Cleared "var/cache" and "var/session" folder
5. Changed file permission to 775 to avoid any permission error

After applying all these errors, the problem is still not resolved. Log-in to admin still shows blank page or redirects to same page. I think it's the issue of session cookie. I desperately need help in this. Please i beg someone to solve this issue. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you using Chrome? Try Firefox or IE.

Comment: as you said their is some time blank page.their might be some error thats why it is showing blank page.you can see the error by commentouting #ini_set('display_errors', 1); from your root index.php and post again with that error.

Comment: @PradeepSanku I checked error log and php curl library was not installed on the server. I installed it and it's working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue. However, i saw many magento beginners struggle in their first attempt of moving magento from localhost to live server and there is no one place solution for this. Here, i tried to make this post a one place solution for this issue with a useful links that i referred and some other steps so that you guys don't have to google much.

1. [chapagain's blog for step by step guide to move magento from one server to another](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/moving-magento-from-one-server-to-another-step-by-step-guide/)

Apart from the steps mentioned in this blog, you must do some more steps in order to make it work.

1. In database table "core_config_data" change "web/cookie/cookie_path" to "/"
2. Again, change "web/cookie/cookie_domain" to ".yourdomain.com"
3. comment out some line of code in "app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php" shown as below

   In magento 1.8.1.0, it is in line 88 to 94.

   ```
       $cookieParams = array(
           'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
           'path'     => $cookie->getPath()/*,
           'domain'   => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
           'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),
           'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly() */
       );
   ```

This should solve the issues in moving magento from localhost to live server. But, if you are still having problem to log-in as admin like i had then check your log file. In my case, i had to install "PHP curl library".

I hope this will help others.